# Marking application without web.xml distributable for Tomcat session replication

Tags: java, xml, spring, session, tomcat

I have Spring based application and using programmatic approach (`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`) for app configuration.

To make tomcat session replication work I need to 'mark' app [distributable](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) using `<distributable/>` tag in `web.xml`, however as I mentioned I am using programmatic style, e.g.

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

            String activeProfile = activeProfile();

            if (isNotEmpty(activeProfile)) {
                servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", activeProfile);
            }

            super.onStartup(servletContext);

        }
    }
```

I can't find any docs about how to do it using Spring configs, so my question here is that, Is it possible to have distributable app without having web.xml? I can't move all configs to the web.xml, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several option you cannot set from Java based configuration, one of them is `<distributable />` another is the `error-pages`.

For that you still need a `web.xml`, just create an as empty as possible `web.xml` and only include `<distributable />`. Everything else can remain in Java based configuration.

```
<web-app
        version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <distributable />

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to already be answered here... [Mixing web.xml and AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137626/mixing-web-xml-and-abstractannotationconfigdispatcherservletinitializer-in-sprin) 
Unless I am misunderstanding the question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure the Cluster programmatically using Spring. One solution is to have a mix of XML and Java based configuration. So that the Web.xml entries can be maintained.
An example is [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mixing-xml-and-javaconfig/) to do this.