# Mixing web.xml and AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer in Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

I have an application on Spring and using Java Configs to configure and initialize my application, so that I have no `web.xml`. Here is how my web initializer looks like,

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{PublicApiConfig.class, MobileConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/*"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        LoggingFilter loggingFilter = new LoggingFilter();
        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter, loggingFilter};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }
}
```

I need to implement tomcat session replication, and for the sake of purpose I need to have application as [distributable](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html). With traditional web.xml I could add `<distributable/>` attribute and thats it. However as far as I understand there is no way to do this via Java Configs.

My question is if it is possible to have mixed web.xml and java configs, e.g. to have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <distributable/>

</web-app>
```

and include it in `WebInitializer`.

Comment: Yes, you can mix them, but what I don't get is, even with this web.xml present you are getting error that web.xml is not present?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Servlet 3.0 specification its possible to mix web.xml with Programmatic servlet registration as long as web-app version >= 3.0 and metadata-complete attribute is false (default). With your current configuration it should work

Comment: thanks for response. But how do I include this web-fragment.xml  file in WebInitializer class? Via Import?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory, and there

```
@Override
public void customize(Context context){
            context.setDistributable(true);
        }
```

You find a complete code example in this thread
[spring-boot-application-with-embedded-tomcat-session-clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623311/how-to-setup-a-spring-boot-application-with-embedded-tomcat-session-clustering)

**Edit : I am not using Spring Boot in this case, and TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory is not available**

The javadoc of [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) says, its possible to use it together with a web.xml :

> WEB-INF/web.xml and WebApplicationInitializer use are not mutually exclusive; for example, web.xml can register one servlet, and a WebApplicationInitializer can register another. An initializer can even modify registrations performed in web.xml through methods such as ServletContext#getServletRegistration(String).

Comment: I am not using Spring Boot in this case, and TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory is not available